# Sharepoint alerts based on file name or content tags

Tags: alert

We have a Sharepoint report library that various different reports are uploaded to, which are from relevant pages/users based on their content tags.

We want to allow users to subscribe to their own reports, preferably based on the content tags, but if this isn't possible, then the filename. However, the manage alerts screen does not seem to offer this functionality, and users can only subscribe to all reports in the library, or none.

So is there a way to achieve this without having to set up a separate report library for each type of report, of which there are 100s? It is also important that the users are able to manage their own alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: I think there is an option when setting up an alert to "only alert me for items that show up in a particular view" and you can pick the view.

If you had a separate view for different categories of items (e.g. ContentTag A, ContentTag B, etc.) then users could set up an alert for each view (content tag) they are interested in and only items that met the view criteria would fire off an alert.